# Problem with Adafruit IO/Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe/Arduino

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide, adafruit

I have problem with Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe.
This is some of my code:

`mqtt = Adafruit_MQTT_Client(&client, AIO_SERVER2, AIO_SERVERPORT2, aioUsername.getValue(), aioKey.getValue()); trigger = Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe(&mqtt, feed);`

When my feed = "username/feeds/trigger"

`aioKey.getValue()); trigger = Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe(&mqtt, "username/feeds/trigger");`

everything is fine, but i want to change the username dynamically. I want to get it from wifiManager parameter.

`String topic = String(aioUsername.getValue()) + "/feeds/trigger"; const char* feed = topic.c_str();`

If i do that I see "MQTT ERROR: rejected, not a valid topic format" on AdafruitIO dashboard.
Please help.

[image: MQTT Error]

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use the example [**ConfigOnDRD_FS_MQTT_Ptr**](https://github.com/khoih-prog/ESP_WiFiManager/tree/master/examples/ConfigOnDRD_FS_MQTT_Ptr) of my [**ESP_WiFiManager**](https://github.com/khoih-prog/ESP_WiFiManager)

```
/****************************************************************************************************************************
 This example will open a Config Portal when there is no stored WiFi Credentials or when a DRD is detected.
 
 You can reconfigure to use another pin, such as the convenience FLASH / BOOT button @ PIN_D0;.
  
 A password is required to connect to the Config Portal so that only who know the password can access the Config Portal.
 
 The Credentials, being input via Config Portal, will then be saved into LittleFS / SPIFFS file, and be used to connect to 
 Adafruit MQTT Server at "io.adafruit.com" and publish a Temperature Topic
 
 Based on original sketch posted by "Marko"(https://github.com/wackoo-arduino) on https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=692108
*****************************************************************************************************************************/
```